# Mandrill - No message exists with id

Tags: ruby, mandrill

I'm having an issue using the mandrill API for ruby and i'm not sure if it's a lack of ruby/api understanding on my part of if there's an issue with the mandrill api.

I have this method which sends an email with mandrill, and then I make another api call using the id returned from `mandrill.messages.send` to make another call to mandrill to get the email header `message-id` so i can store that in a db table.

Why am I getting the error `Mandrill::UnknownMessageError (No message exists with the id '64fba1cce24942dea1ada4f905fd7871'):` when the id clearly exists as seen in the comments for the logging events?

```
# Sends an email to all users for the account_id on the issue
def send_email

    require 'mandrill'  

    ...

    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new Mandrill::API_KEY

    # Email contents
    message = {  
        :subject => self.name,  
        :from_name => self.account.subdomain,  
        :text => self.description,  
        :to => [{
            :email => user.email,
            :name => user.name
        }],
        :text => self.description,  
        :from_email => "noreply@myapp.com",
        :headers => {
            'reply-to' => 'update@myapp.com'
        }
    }  

    results = mandrill.messages.send message # Send email through mandrill

    # Loop through results of sent email
    results.each do |result|

        logger.debug "result id = #{result['_id']}"  # LOGS result id = 64fba1cce24942dea1ada4f905fd7871
        logger.debug "result = #{result}"  # LOGS result = {"email"=>"tomcaflisch@gmail.com", "status"=>"sent", "_id"=>"64fba1cce24942dea1ada4f905fd7871", "reject_reason"=>nil}

        id = result['_id']  # Mandrill's internal id from api call results that sent the email

        # CAUSES Mandrill::UnknownMessageError (No message exists with the id '64fba1cce24942dea1ada4f905fd7871'):
        info = mandrill.messages.content id # Get info for sent email with a specific mandrill id

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to give it a little bit of time.

Comment: Based only on a couple of tests it indeed seems that after a few MINUTES, the result comes back as expected instead of saying "No message exists". Strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error on messages.info(id).

However, search('*') is finding all messages sent but not providing correct status information.

I think the following snippet of gem code is getting 500 status (instead of 200) when messages.info(id) is called:

```
    def call(url, params={})
        params[:key] = @apikey
        params = JSON.generate(params)
        r = @session.post(:path => "#{@path}#{url}.json", :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}, :body => params)

        cast_error(r.body) if r.status != 200
        return JSON.parse(r.body)
    end
```

Also, gem code is hosted on bitbucket instead of more common github. Not sure how to raise an issue there for support.

Sorry can't be of much help but thought I should share my experience also to get more visibility for the problem.